# vis-network not loading on salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, vis.js-network

I am using vis-network module and vis.DataSet() constructor is working perfect on my local pc but on salesforce in helper.js it's giving error as vis.DataSet() is not a constructor.

<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.visNetwork}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}" />

this c.init function is not executing. But in network console visNetwork script is being loaded with response code 200.

this is the link to the vis-network script i am using
https://unpkg.com/vis-network@9.1.6/standalone/umd/vis-network.js

How can i modify my script so that it loads script correctly.